# Testing Backbone applications with Jasmine and Sinon

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jasmine

When **Testing Backbone applications with Jasmine and Sinon**, can we **call** a backbone Model / **View function directly into Jasmine** JS Framework application.

If it is possible, then please help me how to call Backbone function into Jasmine application?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend working through Jim Newberry's excellent tutorial on testing backbone with Jasmine.
He walks through pretty much every aspect of unit testing with Jasmine and Backbone.
The short answer is yes, absolutely.

http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/03/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon.html